# How to get last inserted row from table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table is like below:

```
Id  Data   Date 
A   abc    2016-10-01 00:00:00
A   def    2015-05-20 00:00:00
B   xyz    2014-05-20 00:00:00
B   uvw    2016-10-01 00:00:00
B   rst    2015-10-01 00:00:00
```

I need to get the last inserted row by column Id. So expected output will be:

```
Id  Data   Date
A   def    2015-05-20 00:00:00
B   rst    2015-10-01 00:00:00
```

I can be able to get the last inserted row by Identity column or by inserted date column if I have. But how to get last inserted row without these columns?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the last inserted row ID (with SQL statement)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477502/get-the-last-inserted-row-id-with-sql-statement)

Comment: Your output doesn't make sense.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no concept of *last* record, unless a column specifies that ordering.  The obvious candidates in your case (`id` and `date`) don't work.  Hence, you cannot do what you want to do.

Comment: Please check my updated answer and let me know work for you Or not so i can help you ahead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`row_number()` is the typical way of doing this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: It gives me this output:

Comment: Id Data Date seqnum
A abc 2016-10-01 00:00:00 1
B uvw 2016-10-01 00:00:00 1

Answer (score 1):

Use **PARTITION BY** AND **ORDER BY** WITH **ROW_NUMBER()**:

```
;With T AS 
(
    SELECT
        T1.*,
        T2.NoOfCount,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T1.Id ORDER BY T1.Id DESC) AS PartNo
    FROM @tblTest T1
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            ID, COUNT(*) AS NoOfCount       
        FROM @tblTest
        GROUP BY ID
    ) T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID
)
SELECT
    T.ID,
    T.Data,
    T.Date
FROM T 
WHERE T.PartNo=T.NoOfCount
```

**OR**

```
;With T AS 
(
    SELECT
        T1.*,           
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T1.Id ORDER BY T1.Id DESC) AS PartNo
    FROM @tblTest T1        
),
W AS
(
    SELECT
        ID, COUNT(*) AS NoOfCount       
    FROM @tblTest
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT 
    T.ID,
    T.Data,
    T.Date
FROM T
LEFT JOIN W ON T.ID=W.ID
WHERE T.PartNo=W.NoOfCount
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an undocumented way:

[Equivalent of Oracle's RowID in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909155/equivalent-of-oracles-rowid-in-sql-server)

If you really need to use the row number, use an identity column.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
from table t1
where date = (Select max(date)
    from table t2
    where t2.id = t1.id)
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table
ORDER BY Id DESC
```

In my endeavour to give the **simplest** solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 * FROM table
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: *"I can be able to get the last inserted row by Identity column or by inserted date column if I have. But how to get last inserted row without these columns?"* - This fails to meet the requirement spelled out in the question.

Comment: *"I can be able to get the last inserted row by Identity column **or by inserted date column** if I have. But how to get last inserted row **without these columns**?"*