# How to know the storage address of a record in Azure Database

Tags: sql, azure, records

In Oracle we have RowID, gives [Physical address](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) of a record.
Likewise we have [%%physloc%%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909155/equivalent-of-oracles-rowid-in-sql-server) in SQL Server. What is the keyword for fetching the Physical location of a record in Azure DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Azure SQL Database service is a PaaS (Platform as a Service) service, it abstracts out the need to care or worry about the physical disks that store your data. The service managing scaling everything in your database according to the pricing tier and DTU's you select. As a result of this there are no queries that can be performed to tell where on disk you data is stored. Also, there are no queries to specify where in physical storage you want Azure SQL Database to put your database tables and data. Azure SQL Database just manages all this for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Let's say I'm having a record duplicated in the table. Every column is similar. I want to remove the latest record among them. We can use the RowID in Oracle. In same scenario with Azure, how can we handle?