# How to delete duplicate records in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This my original table:

[image]

Intended table:

[image]

I can't add a new column to table.

Comment: How do you decide which ones are the "good ones" and which ones are the "bad ones"?

Comment: I think the main issue here originates in the absence of a primary key.

Comment: SQL Server questions need to show an attempt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can delete duplicates using i.e. `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
with duplicates as
(
    select
        *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FirstName, LastName, age ORDER BY FirstName) AS number
    from yourTable
)
delete 
from duplicates
where number > 1
```

Each row where `number` is bigger than 1 is a duplicate.

Comment: careful, you didn't partition by `Age` as well which **is needed** to remove true *duplicates*

Answer (score 4):

You can use a common table expression to delete all but the first record in a set of duplicates:

```
with cte as (
    select *, row_number()
     over (partition by FirstName, LastName, Age order by FirstName, LastName, Age) as row_number
    from tbl
)
delete from cte where row_number <> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some way of identifying the rows in the absence of a PK.

The only way I can think of is to:

1. Retrieve the "Row IDs" of the rows,
2. Then pick one as the "good one" for every non-unique row,
3. And finally delete all the other ones.

I'm not positive about this solution, though. I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909155/equivalent-of-oracles-rowid-in-sql-server) can help to produce distinctive row ids. I hope it helps.