# Alter table add multiple columns ms sql

Tags: sql-server-2005

Can anyone tell me where is the mistake in the following query

```
ALTER TABLE Countries
ADD ( 
HasPhotoInReadyStorage  bit,
 HasPhotoInWorkStorage  bit,
 HasPhotoInMaterialStorage bit,
 HasText  bit);

ALTER TABLE Regions
ADD ( HasPhotoInReadyStorage  bit,
 HasPhotoInWorkStorage  bit,
 HasPhotoInMaterialStorage bit
 HasText  bit);

ALTER TABLE Provinces
ADD ( HasPhotoInReadyStorage  bit,
 HasPhotoInWorkStorage  bit,
 HasPhotoInMaterialStorage bit
 HasText  bit);


ALTER TABLE Cities
ADD ( HasPhotoInReadyStorage  bit,
 HasPhotoInWorkStorage  bit,
 HasPhotoInMaterialStorage bit
 HasText  bit);

Alter table Hotels
Add 
{
 HasPhotoInReadyStorage  bit,
 HasPhotoInWorkStorage  bit,
 HasPhotoInMaterialStorage bit,
 HasHotelPhotoInReadyStorage  bit,
 HasHotelPhotoInWorkStorage  bit,
 HasHotelPhotoInMaterialStorage bit,
 HasReporterData  bit,
 HasMovieInReadyStorage  bit,
 HasMovieInWorkStorage  bit,
 HasMovieInMaterialStorage bit
};
```

I get the following errors:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
Incorrect syntax near '{'.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add multiple columns to sql table and add default constraint on one of them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184939/how-to-add-multiple-columns-to-sql-table-and-add-default-constraint-on-one-of-th)

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Take out the parentheses and the curly braces, neither are required when adding columns.

Comment: Also check your commas, looks like you're missing several for the second-to-last columns being added

Answer (score 196):

You need to remove the brackets

```
ALTER TABLE Countries
ADD  
HasPhotoInReadyStorage  bit,
 HasPhotoInWorkStorage  bit,
 HasPhotoInMaterialStorage bit,
 HasText  bit;
```

Comment: And to drop multiple columns: `ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP COLUMN MyCol1, MyCol2, MyCol3`

Answer (score 40):

this should work in T-SQL

```
ALTER TABLE Countries  ADD
HasPhotoInReadyStorage  bit,  
HasPhotoInWorkStorage  bit,  
HasPhotoInMaterialStorage bit,  
HasText  bit GO
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: be careful not to include the GO - that is only used in MSSQL server mgmt studio but it is not a valid sql keyword.

Answer (score 10):

```
Alter table Hotels 
Add  
{ 
 HasPhotoInReadyStorage  bit, 
 HasPhotoInWorkStorage  bit, 
 HasPhotoInMaterialStorage bit, 
 HasHotelPhotoInReadyStorage  bit, 
 HasHotelPhotoInWorkStorage  bit, 
 HasHotelPhotoInMaterialStorage bit, 
 HasReporterData  bit, 
 HasMovieInReadyStorage  bit, 
 HasMovieInWorkStorage  bit, 
 HasMovieInMaterialStorage bit 
};
```

Above you are using {, }.

Also, you are missing commas:

```
ALTER TABLE Regions 
ADD ( HasPhotoInReadyStorage  bit, 
 HasPhotoInWorkStorage  bit, 
 HasPhotoInMaterialStorage bit <**** comma needed here
 HasText  bit);
```

You need to remove the brackets and make sure all columns have a comma where necessary.

Answer (score 10):

Can with default value (T-SQL)

```
ALTER TABLE
    Regions
ADD
    HasPhotoInReadyStorage BIT NULL, --this column is nullable
    HasPhotoInWorkStorage BIT NOT NULL, --this column is not nullable
    HasPhotoInMaterialStorage BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0), --this column is not nullable and set default value is 0(zero)
    HasPhotoInThingStorage BIT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_HasPhotoInThingStorage DEFAULT(0) --this column is not nullable and set default value is 0(zero) with spesific constraint name
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ALTER TABLE Regions
ADD ( HasPhotoInReadyStorage  bit,
     HasPhotoInWorkStorage  bit,
     HasPhotoInMaterialStorage bit *(Missing ,)*
     HasText  bit);
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Extending the codingbadger's answer to assign a default value

```
ALTER TABLE Countries
ADD  
HasPhotoInReadyStorage bit DEFAULT 1 WITH VALUES,
 HasPhotoInWorkStorage bit DEFAULT 0 WITH VALUES,
 HasPhotoInMaterialStorage bit DEFAULT 0 WITH VALUES,
 HasText bit DEFAULT 1 WITH VALUES;
```