# How to add multiple columns to a table and add default constraint on one of them?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to add 2 new columns to existing table.

One of them should be `NOT NULL` with default value *0*
(filled in the existing rows as well).

I have tried the following syntax:

```
Alter TABLE dbo.MamConfiguration
    add [IsLimitedByNumOfUsers] [bit]  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT IsLimitedByNumOfUsers_Defualt [IsLimitedByNumOfUsers] DEFAULT 0
    [NumOfUsersLimit] [int] NULL
go
```

But it throws exception. How should I write it?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MamConfiguration
ADD [IsLimitedByNumOfUsers] [BIT] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,   
    [NumOfUsersLimit] [INT] NULL
GO
```

or this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MamConfiguration
ADD [IsLimitedByNumOfUsers] [BIT] NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT IsLimitedByNumOfUsers_Default DEFAULT 0,
    [NumOfUsersLimit] [INT] NULL
go
```

More: [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

Comment: I would always recommend option #2 - give your constraints *explicit names* - makes it a lot easier if you need to drop them later on!

Comment: @marc_s: yeah, I strongly agree with you!

Comment: I never noticed that you could use a `,` between columns to be added. What a time saver if you are adding a lot of new columns to an existing table!

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MamConfiguration  
ADD [IsLimitedByNumOfUsers] [bit]  NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,     
[NumOfUsersLimit] [int] NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

**To add multiple columns to a table and add default constraint on one of them-**

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MamConfiguration
ADD [IsLimitedByNumOfUsers] [BIT] CONSTRAINT Def_IsLimitedByNumOfUsers DEFAULT(0) NOT NULL,   
    [NumOfUsersLimit] [INT] NULL;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Each column is different;

```
ALTER TABLE
    MamConfiguration
ADD
    Configuration1 BIT NULL, --this column is nullable
    Configuration2 BIT NOT NULL, --this column is not nullable
    Configuration3 BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0), --this column is not nullable and set default value is 0(zero)
    Configuration4 BIT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Configuration4 DEFAULT(0) --this column is not nullable and set default value is 0(zero) with spesific constraint name
GO
```