# Automatically add and persist the current date in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to create a database which has one date column that needs to be automatically filled with the current date. 
I tried the following design in Sql Management Studio:
[image]

The problem with this desing is that every time I insert a new record to the table, all DateEffective rows change to the current date, and I need only the last row to change.
Is there any solution to this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: find your answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4888388/94334

Answer (score 0):

try creating a trigger for this:

[Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)