# While adding data to db, date column is set to getdate() but gives an error, date can't be empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-6.0

I am making a resgistration form in ASP.NET Core and this is how my table schema looks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tg1HD.png)

The idCreatedTime field is a datetime field and has default value set to getdate(). When a user submits the registration form, where I am only asking for his username, emailId and password as the other two fields are auto value fields,I get this error

> SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'idCreatedTime', table 'PoliticalData.dbo.UserData'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
> The statement has been terminated.

Registration form

```html
@page
@model IndianPoliticalData.Pages.UserCredentials.RegisterModel

<div>
    <form method="post">        
        <label>Enter Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" asp-for="UserData.Username" placeholder="Enter Username"/>

        <label>Enter EmailId</label>
        <input type="email" name="EmailId" asp-for="UserData.EmailId" placeholder="Enter Email"/>

        <label>Enter Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" asp-for="UserData.Password" placeholder="Enter Password" />

        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Code that inserts data to the db

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await _context.UserData.AddAsync(UserData);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToPage("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Just sharing the required columns

```cs
[Column("password")]
[StringLength(50)]
[Unicode(false)]
public string Password { get; set; } = null!;
        
[Column("emailId")]
[StringLength(50)]
[Unicode(false)]
public string EmailId { get; set; } = null!;

// Just added DateTime.UtcNow to check if that works.
[Column("idCreatedTime", TypeName = "datetime")]
public DateTime? IdCreatedTime { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

[InverseProperty("User")]
public virtual ICollection<Bookmark> Bookmarks { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you share the code which inserts the data into table?

Comment: @Chetan added it, plz check it out

Comment: Can you show the data model `UserData`?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? How you set default value? Like this [Default values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#default-values)?

Comment: Specify the exact version of EF.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing an insert from the SQL Management Studio (or any other client) to see if that works?

```
INSERT INTO PoliticalData.dbo.UserData (username, password, emailId) 
VALUES ('dummy_username', 'dummy_password', 'somemail@domain.com');
```

If it does work this may be a missconfiguration in the ORM you are using, either it is EntityFramework or any other.

Also, have you tried the different solutions pointed out on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888277/add-default-value-of-datetime-field-in-sql-server-to-a-timestamp)?

Comment: It works the way it should, does create a unique id and also adds the current date and time on my computer and yes I am using entity framework

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `IdCreatedTime` property on `UserData` is probably null so that Entity Framework tries to insert a null value into the database. To avoid this, set the property before inserting the row in the database:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    Userdata.IdCreatedTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    await _context.UserData.AddAsync(UserData);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToPage("Index");
  }
  else
  {
    return Page();
  }
}
```

If you want to avoid having null values in the property, change the definition of the column from a `Nullable<DateTime>` to a `DateTime` by removing the question mark:

```
[Column("idCreatedTime", TypeName = "datetime")]
public DateTime IdCreatedTime { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Comment: What do I need to add to the ID feild, so that it gets me unique id's everytime

Comment: @JankiDave in order to get the Id of the inserted row, add a `public int Id { get; set; }` property to your class and read the value of the property after `SaveChangesAsync`.