# Add a column of zeros to table sql server

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add column, with default value, to existing table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92082/add-column-with-default-value-to-existing-table-in-sql-server)

I have a table in sql server, but want to add a extra column full of zeros

What would be the best approach to do this

```
att1 att2
---------
1.0   5.8
2.7   3.8
5.1   6.8
```

becomes

```
att1 att2  extra
----------------
1.0   5.8   0.0
2.7   3.8   0.0
5.1   6.8   0.0
```

Comment: The default should be 0, so all you have to do is add the column.

Comment: Travis, default is NULL isn't it?  so if you specify it not null that would probably default it to zero.  Anyway, same as the other question.

Comment: Whatever you are doing that requires this, stop now. It is a bad idea. Why store data that is always the same?

Comment: Could be a 'starting point' where some process will come along later and amend *some* of the rows. Default of 0's prevents having to deal with NULLs...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If I recall correctly, it should be something like:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
ADD extra REAL DEFAULT 0
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx

See: [Add a column with a default value to an existing table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92082/add-column-with-default-value-to-existing-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: I tried it ,but get the column full of NULL...

Comment: if the column is nullable must add the `WITH VALUES` clause: `alter table table_name add extra real default 0 with values;`

Answer (score 4):

I understand this column will always have value of 0.0. Then it does not have to be a real column

```
CREATE TABLE extraColumn (
     att1   float  NULL
    ,att2   float  NULL
    ,extra AS 0.0 
)
```

But if you need that, you can persist it

```
CREATE TABLE extraColumn (
     att1   float  NULL
    ,att2   float  NULL
    ,extra AS 0.0  PERSISTED 
)
```