# Setting default value and displaying in checkboxes

Tags: c#, sql

Okay so this is a bit of a double question problem, but they are both related. The first question is how would I set a default value for my column as I want it to be true/1 (it's a bit column in case you hadn't guessed) and the second issue is that I have a row of checkboxes and I want these to be ticked when I have the value set as true, my current command is:

```
cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE tbl_ecom_cat_feature ADD display_on_search BIT";
```

Comment: Your first question answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92082/add-column-with-default-value-to-existing-table-in-sql-server, the second could be possible if you are using bool fields for the bind

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't know how to give a great comment reply but thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Get Default Value Use :
 SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Where ...

For Set Default Value Use :
ALTER TABLE {TABLENAME}  ADD {COLUMNNAME} {TYPE} {NULL|NOT NULL}  CONSTRAINT {CONSTRAINT_NAME} DEFAULT {DEFAULT_VALUE}

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you already have created the column, you could send this command

```
cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE tbl_ecom_cat_feature ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_tbl_ecom_cat_feature_display_on_search]  DEFAULT (1) FOR [display_on_search]
```

To answer your second question I need to know where you display your data.
If it is a DataGridView then I think you should set the corresponding column to DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn.aspx)

Comment: Well, the programs UI is using WPF and the data is displayed in a column called "Display On Search" that has a row of checkboxes that currently show up based on if the "Name" column isn't null

Comment: In a more informative responce, here is how I am doing it in my XML file

Comment: Not an expert on WPF, but I see that there is the same pattern there.  DataGrid and [DataGridCheckBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcheckboxcolumn.aspx)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BQkcxupU - This includes the xmal.cs method that is used to show it.