# Having trouble setting a computed column as not Null

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

I'm having problems setting a computed column as `not null`.

What I want to achieve is `C001`,`C002...`, etc. and at the same time set it as `not null`.

I have read on a forum that this can be achieved by using the default value 0 for NULL values.
E.g., `ISNULL(Price + Taxes, 0)`

I have tried to apply to this formula:

```
('C'+right('000'+CONVERT([varchar](3),[ID],(0)),(3)))
```

But it didn't seem to work. Can anyone tell me what am I missing?

```
ALTER CreditCard accountNo AS ISNULL('C'+right('000'+CONVERT([varchar](3),[idCreditCard],(0)),(3)),0)
```

Comment: Your alter statement with `isnull` creates a column that does not allow nulls. At least in my tests. However you are missing a `add` between the table name and the column name.

Comment: Yup. What I'm trying to create is a column that does not allow null. I tried adding an add between the table name and the column name but it didn't work.

Comment: But... eh.. Thats what I said. It *does* create a column that does not allow nulls. What happened for you? What did not work?

Comment: Please be more specific when you ask a question, make sure it's easy to understand what you try to achieve and if you are asking a question related to databases you should also add a tag with your RDBMS to the question.

Comment: As in when i tried to alter my column accountNo to don't allow nulls, I reveived an Error message: Unknown object type 'CreditCard' used in a create, drop or alter statement

Comment: You don't need to alter the column. If the computed column uses `isnull` then it is defined with `not null`. If you need to modify an already existing computed column you first need to drop the column and then add it again with the new formula.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what database you're using, but its more common to use an `ALTER TABLE` statement. e.g. [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) [This is also a very popular question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92082/add-column-with-default-value-to-existing-table-in-sql-server) regarding the syntax for SQL Server

Comment: Oh my bad....I thought I could modify the column without dropping the column, anyway thanks for your help, I've finally found the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've finally found the solution to my problem!

The correct query should be:

```
ALTER TABLE CreditCard ADD accountNo AS ISNULL('C'+right('000'+CONVERT([varchar](3),[idCreditCard],(0)),(3)),0)
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 3):

If this relates to SQL Server, you might be interested in this from MSDN.

*'NOT NULL can be specified for computed columns only if PERSISTED is also specified.'*
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx

... but after trying to reverse-engineering the question from the answer, I think that 'keenlearner wanted only to ensure that there was never a null value in the column without having the constraint.