# SQL trigger, check if certain value was entered

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Now what to check:

**If inserted value1 = null, change it to 0**

How to do it via trigger? I googled for examples and I have never ever done a trigger, so it is rather confusing.

So far got only this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER testTrigger
ON myTable
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add **default value** . This is how it's done for a new column. For existing one you should add constraint. Check ***Update 2***

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
ADD column1 int NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
```

[Add a column with a default value to an existing table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92082/add-column-with-default-value-to-existing-table-in-sql-server)

**UPDATE:**

To set default value, you should update NULL values at first.

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET column1 = 0
WHERE column1 IS NULL
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Try adding constraint

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_column1 DEFAULT 0 FOR column1
```

Comment: This adds column, can I change to columns default value?

Comment: You should update column1 values to 0 after that alter column. Check update.

Comment: `alter table myTable alter column myColumn varchar(40) not null default('0')`, gives INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR THE KEYWORD 'DEFAULT'

Answer (score 12):

You could write this in the trigger:

```
UPDATE T SET value1 =0
FROM   table_name T
JOIN   INSERTED I
ON     T.<id>=I.<id>
WHERE  I.value1 is null
```

INSERTED  table which is accessible only within trigger will store the values that have inserted..

Answer (score 2):

use ISNULL on the **INSERTED** value

```
 SELECT ISNULL(INSERTED,0) FROM INSERTED
```