# Trigger after insert on not null column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a table that contains two `not null` columns `Created` and `Updated`.

I wrote corresponding triggers

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_category_inserted] ON [dbo].[Category]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE Category
  SET Created = GETDATE(), Updated = GETDATE()
  FROM inserted
  WHERE Category.ID = inserted.ID;
END
```

and

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_category_updated] ON [dbo].[Category]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE Category
  SET Updated = GETDATE()
    FROM inserted
        inner join [dbo].[Category] c on c.ID = inserted.ID
END
```

but if I am inserting a new row I get an error

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Created', table
>   'Category'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Insert command:

```
INSERT INTO [Category]([Name], [ShowInMenu], [Deleted])
     VALUES ('category1', 0, 0)
```

How can I write such triggers without a setting to these columns to allow null?

Comment: If you want to update `date` automatically on `insert`, i suggest you to use `default` constraint instead of `triggers`

Comment: Error occurring because trigger works after insertion only, and you may not be inserting the column values `Created` and `Updated` at the time of insert.

Comment: As the name of the trigger already says, the trigger fires **AFTER** the insert has happened - but you need to provide a **value** upon `INSERT` for any `NOT NULL` column. So you either need to write an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger to set the initial value of those columns -or much easier: just define a `DEFAULT (GETDATE())` constraint on that column so it will automatically be filled on `INSERT` ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable MODIFY COLUMN updated timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
ALTER TABLE yourTable MODIFY COLUMN created timestamp DEFAULT 0;
```

Set the default for the created to column to 0. Unfortunately MySQL does not allow two timestamp columns with default `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in one table. To overcome this you just have to insert a `NULL` value into `created` column and you will have both columns to the current timestamp.

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (col1, created) VALUES ('whatever', NULL);
```

Or you set the default to a valid timestamp like

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable MODIFY COLUMN created timestamp DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00';
```

and modify your trigger like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_category_inserted] ON [dbo].[Category]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE Category
  SET Created = GETDATE()
/*  FROM inserted */ /*don't know where you got that from, do you port from SQL Server?*/
  WHERE Category.ID = NEW.ID;
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Error occurring because trigger works after insertion only, and you may not be inserting the column values `Created` and `Updated` at the time of insert.

So for eliminating the error, you can insert/populate the columns `Created` and `Updated` along with insert.
OR
You can add default value property of column. Please check the links for details

[Add column, with default value, to existing table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92082/add-column-with-default-value-to-existing-table-in-sql-server)

[Specify Default Values for Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187872.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Possible use [**INSTEAD OF**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_category_inserted] ON [dbo].[Category]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT Category(Name, ShowInMenu, Deleted, Created, Updated)
  SELECT Name, ShowInMenu, Deleted, GETDATE(), GETDATE()
  FROM inserted i
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically allow the last updated column to be null since I want to know if its never been altered. If you must keep both fields nullable I would add a default value to those columns like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Category] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Created]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Category] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [LastUpdated]
GO
```

Then you won't need the trigger for the insert.

If you really want to use a trigger anyway you will have to specify `INSTEAD OF` rather than `AFTER` and include the insert statement.