# How do I add a column, with a default value, to an existing table in SQL Server 2008 or 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How do I add a column, with a default value, to an existing table in SQLServer 2008?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE {TABLENAME} 
ADD {COLUMNNAME} {TYPE} {NULL|NOT NULL} 
CONSTRAINT {CONSTRAINT_NAME} DEFAULT {DEFAULT_VALUE}`

[Add a column with a default value to an existing table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92082/add-column-with-default-value-to-existing-table-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 9):

Use [`ALTER TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx). For example

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 
ADD  col2 INT DEFAULT 0;
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1925/1)**

Comment: As a general rule, it is best to name your constraints. If you don't it will get a random name, and they will differ between different databases (eg at different client installations). This will make scripting changes difficult in some cases (ie you will have to resort to workarounds).

Comment: @TT. Fair point. Agreed.