# How do I see the script of a table in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I right click on the table name I click on `select top 1000 rows` and it gives me this script

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP 1000 [response_id]
      ,[submitter]
      ,[submitterdept]
      ,[employee]
      ,[employeedept]
      ,[rating1]
      ,[rating2]
      ,[rating3]
      ,[rating4]
      ,[rating5]
      ,[commentpositive]
      ,[commentnegative]
      ,[star]
      ,[commentdate]
      ,[status]
      ,[approvedby]
      ,[approveddate]
      ,[execoffice_status]
      ,[execoffice_approvedby]
      ,[execoffice_date]
  FROM [Intranet].[dbo].[CSEReduxResponses]
```

How do I see the script of the table? There is nothing I have tried when I right click on the table that i can see the script.

Comment: I have '10 so... Try a right click on the table name and the Script as... menu.

Comment: There is no MENU option when I right click.

Comment: Do you want to see `select top 10 rows`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

- Open SSMS
- Open Object Explorer (hit F8)
- Connect to a SQL instance
- Open "Databases"
- Open the desired database
- Open "Tables"
- Right-click on the desire table
- In the menu, select "Script table as"
- In the sub-menu, select "Create to"
- In the sub-sub-menu, select "New Query Editor Window"

This will generate a create script and lod it into its own query window.

Here's more detail than you wanted:

- From the SSMS menu, select Tools / Options
- In the dialog window, select "SQL Server Object Explorer"
- Select "Scripting"

Each of the items in the right-hand pane will control an aspect of how and what objects will be scripted by Object Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your SSMS Righ click the Table and follow the path show as below

[image]

This will create the script of your table.

Comment: Thank you. Very different from what Im use to.

Comment: Not a problem glad to help :)

Comment: If i wanted to add a new column to table can I write in in the script and 'execute'?

Comment: This create script is good if you want to create this table in another database as this will try to create another table with the same name and you cannot have two table with the same name in a database. If you want to add a column then you need to use T-Sql Command for that, Using `ALTER TABLE` command, Read this question for more information on this [`Add a Column to an Existing Table`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92082/add-a-column-with-a-default-value-to-an-existing-table-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Your results window isn't sized to where you can see the output. Look towards the bottom of your window, you should see results and messages. Drag it up to display your results. If your results window is completely hidden you can go to "Window" ---> Show Results Pane.

Comment: I can see the output and what is in the table. (Im not use to working with this software, im use to Toad Oracle). Shouldn't there be something that shows me the script, like 'CREATE TABLE...' when it was first created?

Comment: I'm not sure, but what it sounds like to me is that you may be looking for more of a stored procedure. In a stored procedure or Transact-SQL you would see the CREATE. When you use server management studio, a majority of the time you are probably just performing a SELECT statement.