# Android how to fill column when onUpdateDatabase called?

Tags: android, sql

I have a code which called when new database version will be installed on device.

```
    if (oldVersion < 8) {
        try {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("ALTER TABLE `" + Category.controllerName + "` ADD COLUMN " + Category.TYPE + " TEXT");
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        }
    }
```

I suppose this will be created a new Column with name `type`.
How i can fill this column with default value `-1` for example?

And also... how i need support database update correctly? Any links will be appericated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a column, with a default value, to an existing table in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92082/add-a-column-with-a-default-value-to-an-existing-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a default value like this:

```
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("ALTER TABLE `" + Category.controllerName + "` ADD COLUMN " + Category.TYPE + " TEXT DEFAULT -1");
```

More on Alter table :https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html