# In SQL, How to add values after add a new column in the existing table?

Tags: sql, database

I created a table and inserted 3 rows. Then I added a new column using `alter`.  How can I add values to the column without using any null values?

Comment: What values would you like to place there? Can you show your table's structure and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: share your table structure and value your trying put

Comment: What you need could be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92082/add-a-column-with-a-default-value-to-an-existing-table-in-sql-server

Answer (score 33):

Two solutions.

1. Provide a default value for the column. This value will be used initially for all existing rows. The exact syntax depends on your database, but will will usually look like ..

this:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD YourNewColumn INT NOT NULL
DEFAULT 10 
WITH VALUES;
```

2. Add the column with `null` values first. Then update all rows to enter the values you want.

Like so:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD YourNewColumn INT NULL;

UPDATE YourTable SET YourNewColumn = 10; -- Or some more complex expression
```

Then, if you need to, alter the column to make it `not null`:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourNewColumn NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for adding both types of solutions!

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE tablename SET column=value <WHERE ...>
```

WHERE is optional. For instance in T-SQL for table:

[image]

I can update column NewTestColumn by this statement:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Table] SET [NewTestColumn] = 'Some value'
```

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a Employee table with these columns Employee_ID, Emp_Name,Emp_Email initially. Later you decide to add Emp_Department column to this table. To enter values to this column, you can use the following query :

```
Update *Table_Name* set *NewlyAddedColumnName*=Value where *Columname(primary key column)*=value
```

Example `update TblEmployee set Emp_Department='Marketing' where Emp_ID='101'`

Answer (score 1):

I think below SQL useful to you

```
update table_name set newly_added_column_name = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   update table_name
   set new_column=value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update  table_name set column_name = value where 'condition';
```

Answer (score -1):

suppose emp is the table and Comm is the new column then fire the below query .

```
update emp set Comm=5000
```

Answer (score -1):

**For Microsoft SQL (T-SQL):**

`UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN_NAME=10;`

here 10 means it will set all values by default to 10

Answer (score -1):

simply use update query for inserting values into new column .

syntax: update databasename.tablename set columnname=value where columnname=value;

eg.  update company.emp set emp_no=8728483892 where ename="manasi";