# Add Column to Table with Default Value

Tags: sql, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm trying to add a column to a table (ideally without using a dataframe) with a default value of 'MONTHLY'

```
ALTER TABLE aa_monthly ADD COLUMNS (Monthly_or_Weekly_Indicator string NOT NULL FIRST DEFAULT ('MONTHLY'))
```

This gives me an error of:

> Error in SQL statement: ParseException:  mismatched input 'DEFAULT'
>   expecting ')'(line 1, pos 88)

I get the same error regardless of whether or not I have `FIRST` in the sql statement.

I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31807768/in-sql-how-to-add-values-after-add-a-new-column-in-the-existing-table) and [here](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/tables.html#update-a-table)

Answer (score 2):

In Hive you [cannot add a default value for a column](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Add/ReplaceColumns), sadly.

> The column change command will only modify Hive's metadata, and will not modify data

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
ALTER TABLE aa_monthly 
    ADD Monthly_or_Weekly_Indicator string NOT NULL DEFAULT 'MONTHLY'
```

Comment: Ah, I'm getting this error: Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
no viable alternative at input 'ALTER TABLE aa_monthly ADD Monthly_or_Weekly_Indicator'(line 1, pos 35). It's showing the error after 'ADD'

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to that

```
1)  ALTER TABLE aa_monthly 
    ADD Monthly_or_Weekly_Indicator string  not null
    CONSTRAINT Monthly_or_Weekly_Indicator DEFAULT 'MONTHLY'
    WITH VALUES

2)  ALTER TABLE aa_monthly 
    ADD Monthly_or_Weekly_Indicator string NOT NULL DEFAULT 'MONTHLY'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these work. They both get hung up right after 'ADD'. I get the same error: com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
no viable alternative at input 'ALTER TABLE aa_monthly \n    ADD Monthly_or_Weekly_Indicator'(line 2, pos 8)

Comment: Are you hitting this query directly or through any program ??

Comment: directly. I'm using sql in databricks