# Column does not allow null error when trying to insert a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

Tags: sql, sql-server, uniqueidentifier

I want to insert guid values into an existing column called `rowguid` in an existing table.

I've created the column with this statement:

```sql
ALTER TABLE [myschema].[mytablename] 
    ADD rowguid uniqueidentifier
```

The column has been created and it's full of `NULL`s.

I've tried this to generate the IDs for every row:

```sql
INSERT INTO [myschema].[mytablename] (rowguid) 
VALUES(NEWID())
```

But this returns with:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column '[another column name in my table]', table '[database].[schema].[mytablename]'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: The error complains about NULLs, not UNIQUEIDENTIFIER. I suspect the table has other non-nullable columns that need to be set as well

Comment: Yes, the table has other non-nullable columns, but I don't understand what needs to be set.

Comment: Those columns. You can't insert a new row without filling *all* non-nullable columns. `INSERT ... VALUES` inserts a single row. You need to include all non-nullable columns in the column list and provide values for all of them in the `VALUES` clause

Comment: `INSERT` doesn't update the value of a row, that's what `UPDATE` does. Though you would have been better off adding the column with a `DEFAULT` `CONSTRAINT` and using `WITH VALUES` (or probably defining it as `NOT NULL`) if you didn't want the column to be populated with `NULL` values.

Comment: If the *real* question is how to modify the existing rows, use UPDATE, not INSERT, eg `UPDATE thatTable SET ThatColumn=NEWID()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way to update all rows in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635689/efficient-way-to-update-all-rows-in-a-table)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In SQL, How to add values after add a new column in the existing table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31807768/in-sql-how-to-add-values-after-add-a-new-column-in-the-existing-table)

Comment: You can create a new *non*-nullable row by specifying a `DEFAULT` value. This way you can add `rowguid` and fill it at once **BUT**  why do you want this? A GUID is a very bad choice for a PRIMARY or any kind of key. They're bigger than eg `bigint`, can't be used for range queries and cause table fragmentation. You can use `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` to alleviate fragmentation but you still end up wasting space.

Comment: Yes, that is the real question. Problem solved. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Mons why do you want a GUID column at all? Especially one named `rowguid`? A row's identity is its PK. A `rowguid` may make sense in a replication scenario but even there, there may be better options. Unless you use NEWSEQUENTIALID even replication will be impacted - unless you use another feature like Change Tracking