# SQL server query to add column with default value

Tags: sql, sql-server, default-value, alter-table

I'm trying to change my SQL server database by adding another column to a table with 0 as a default value.

I thought this script worked in the past (for another table), but now I have an error when I try to execute the script

> **The script**

```
ALTER TABLE Whatever
ADD WhateverColumn tinyint NOT NULL 
DEFAULT(0)
```

> **The errors**

- On hovering mouse over "NOT": Incorrect syntax near 'NOT'. Expecting 'TO'
- On hovering mouse over "0": Incorrect syntax near 0. Expecting '(', or SELECT

Anyone knows what's wrong with this?

Comment: How/within what are you executing this statement?

Comment: I just created a new query in my SQL server management studio (v17.7)

Comment: Is this the only command in the batch (or the whole input edit box)? I suspect you have something else in there before the `ALTER` and as you apparently don't use terminating semicolons that might confuse the parser.

Comment: This is the only command. There's not even a comment before it

Comment: Did you try to execute it, not to "hover over"?

Comment: I do have an update available for SQL server management studio... Could it be that it's a bug?

Comment: I tried executing it, but it's giving an "incorrect syntax" error there as well

Comment: Open new query window and paste the code there. Try to execute it. The statement is CORRECT

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a column with a default value to an existing table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92082/add-a-column-with-a-default-value-to-an-existing-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: Tried with a new window, but unfortunately... same problem

Comment: Try to execute your statement in sqlcmd.

Comment: Escape `[Whatevertable]` and `[WhateverColumn]` (using the demonstrated brackets) if either contain spaces, special characters or correspond with a T-SQL keyword. Or just generally always, as it's good practice. Also, when in doubt, retype the whole command from scratch instead of copy-pasting anything, as you may have invisible characters somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I expected, updating my SQL Server Management Studio to version 17.8.1 solved my issue.
After updating, I was able to run this command without any problem.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE Whatever
ADD WhateverColumn tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

Comment: This solves the incorrect syntax error on "0" but does not solve the error on the "NOT"

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '‌'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'WhateverColumn'.

Comment: ALTER TABLE taxi_trip_test_Data
  add test tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0

Comment: I've tried with this and it didn't show me any error

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the "Whatever" you are using as the table name has unclosed quotation marks, or even the "WhateverColumn" (both that you place here as a token, i get it) my have this problem, or even the "WhateverColumn" actual name is a reserved word?

Comment: I executed this exact command in the past, but on a different table. I guess the table name shouldn't be the issue?

Comment: my point, as complemented by @Singh-amarjeet, is that you can have problems if the column (problably not the table, since it's been created already) has a name like "system" ou "column", or any other name that can be confused with a key word. Try, just to see, with an mame like "tb_whatever", or if you're confident about it, then it should indeed work, and i can't say more over pseudo-code, need database and table declarations to see

Answer (score 0):

@SammuelMiranda has just asked the same just now. It matters if you are using reserved keyword as table or column name also. 
you can check this link
[Add a column with a default value to an existing table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92082/add-a-column-with-a-default-value-to-an-existing-table-in-sql-server)