# How to add a column in MSSQL with default value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In MSSQL 2014 I would like to use an update syntax which is adding a new column with a default value. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: You should use alter table, not update. visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92082/add-a-column-with-a-default-value-to-an-existing-table-in-sql-server

Comment: This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92082/add-a-column-with-a-default-value-to-an-existing-table-in-sql-server), still works the same with 2014.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a column with a default value to an existing table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92082/add-a-column-with-a-default-value-to-an-existing-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: Hi Peter, greetings from Vienna, welcome on Stackoverflow! Check out [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/9406040) on how to ask a good SQL question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete reproducible example.

## Create table

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees
( employee_id INT NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  salary MONEY
);

INSERT INTO employees
VALUES (1, 'Miller', 'Peter', 80000);

INSERT INTO employees
VALUES (2, 'Myer', 'Joana', 90000);
```

## Check contents

```sql
SELECT * FROM employees;

employee_id last_name   first_name  salary  
1           Miller      Peter       80000   
2           Myer        Joana       90000
```

## Add new column with default value

```sql
ALTER TABLE employees
ADD email VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'info@company.com' NOT NULL;
```

## Check the result

```sql
SELECT * FROM employees;

employee_id last_name   first_name  salary  email
1           Miller      Peter       80000   info@company.com
2           Myer        Joana       90000   info@company.com
```

[Here is a SQL fiddle with this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0ace9/3).

Answer (score 5):

Something Like below:

```
alter table myTable add myNewColumn nvarchar(20) default 'myDefaultValue' not null
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :-

```
CREATE TABLE employees
( employee_id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'jon',
  first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'jona',
  salary MONEY DEFAULT 0
);


ALTER TABLE employees ADD designation VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'TL' NOT NULL;
```

Comment: This creates a **new table** with default values, yes. But it does not update an **existing table**, which I think OP was after.

Comment: Please try now I Added Alter Query also

Comment: Hey Prakash, your SQL statement is faulty. You are adding a constraint instead of a column (and also reference `#employees` instead of `employees`). Happy coding!