# H2 ADD COLUMN Slow

Tags: sql, h2

I have a table with 30k rows. Adding a column (e.g. below) takes ~10 seconds.

I need to add 50-odd columns, but this takes 10 minutes.

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS myCol1 DOUBLE;
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS myCol2 VARCHAR;
```

I've seen this syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD (myCol1 DOUBLE, myCol2 VARCHAR);
```

Which seems faster (or at least, a constant time rather than a multiple off the number of columns) but this doesn't seem to support `IF NOT EXISTS`.

Is there any way to optimise this?

Comment: assuming that this addition is a one-time thing, why wouldn't you create a back up of a table; drop it; create new with all necessary columns; repopulate from a back up. Hope this helps.

Comment: also you can see here how to add multiple columns in one statement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92082/add-a-column-with-a-default-value-to-an-existing-table-in-sql-server?rq=1

Comment: @user2065377 I *can* do that but I'd like to avoid doing that - it's not a one-time thing (it's an embedded database in an application) and there's the risk of missing fields etc this way

I'm not sure how the link you sent is related, but I don't think you can do ``IF EXISTS`` with multiple columns in one statement...?