# Conditionally add a column with a default value to an existing table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add a new column in existing SQL table with default values depending upon some cases/conditions.

I want to know if this is possible. If yes how? if not why?

**Alternative :**

One option is to create the column and then update but approach is out of the question here.

**Let’s consider I have the following table**

```
╔════╦══════════════╗
║ ID ║      Age     ║ 
╠════╬══════════════║
║  1 ║    0.166667  ║   
║  2 ║     0.125    ║   
║  3 ║       13     ║   
║  4 ║       19     ║  
║  5 ║       45     ║  
║  6 ║       59     ║   
║  7 ║       60     ║  
║  8 ║       64     ║ 
╚════╩══════════════╝
```

**Desired output is this :**

```
╔════╦══════════════╦═══════════╗
║ ID ║      Age     ║ AgeGroup  ║
╠════╬══════════════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║    0.166667  ║   NewBorn ║
║  2 ║     0.125    ║   NewBorn ║
║  3 ║       13     ║   Teen    ║
║  4 ║       19     ║   Teen    ║
║  5 ║       45     ║   Adult   ║
║  6 ║       59     ║   Adult   ║
║  7 ║       60     ║  Elder    ║
║  8 ║       64     ║  Elder    ║
╚════╩══════════════╩═══════════╝
```

I have studied this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92082/add-a-column-with-a-default-value-to-an-existing-table-in-sql-server) but this is only for **"Adding column default values"**

EDIT : Here is the SQL [script](https://github.com/sherazahmedse/scripts) with schema and data for the above table for users who wants to test.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here. Do you want a new column on the table or not? What's the condition that the new column depends on? Normally you would put your conditions on a `IF` control flow statement.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "default value?" Is it possible, for example, to later update the value from teen to adult without changing the age?

Comment: @SalmanA Yes I want it to change. Basically add a column with different values in every row depending upon a condition. I want to do it at the time adding a column and don't want to write an update query which does that.

Comment: There is an answer below that suggests using computed columns. But even better solution is to not use computed columns (in your example they simply add noise) and use a CASE statement in your reports/ui to convert age value to labels. Even better would be to store date of birth so that you don't have to increment the age every year.

Comment: @SalmanA this is just a sample data

Comment: Just to clarify the question. If ID 3’s age were changed to 45, should the `AgeGroup` change to match? If so, then you’re not talking about a __default__, but a __computed column__. You should _never_ have two dependent columns, but it’s OK to have a virtual computed column.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may try this. There are basically 2 approach to achieve this.

**Adding Column in table schema**

As I understand you want to add a column in table schema as given link shared by you. You may use `case` statement to add column for calculated values.

**EDIT : Correcting Syntax Error**

```
alter table yourtable
    add AgeGroup as (case 
                        when Age < 2 then 'New Born'
                        when Age < 19 then 'Teen'
                        when Age < 45 then 'Young'
                        when Age > 60 then 'Adult'
                        else 'Invalid' 
                     end);
```

Or

**Create view**

You may create a view for same and use it wherever you needed.

```
Create View TableResult 
As
Select Id, Age, case Age 
                         WHEN Age < 2 then 'New Born'
                         WHEN Age < 19 then 'Teen'
                         WHEN Age < 45 then 'Young'
                         WHEN Age > 60 then 'Adult'
                         else 'Invalid' 
                     end as AgeGroup
End
```

Comment: Adding Column in table schema is the approach that I am after but it throws a syntax error

Comment: There is a Syntax error in your answer which I have corrected "Adding Column in table schema" And thank You it works

Comment: Can we run an SQL query to decide which value to fill?

Answer (score 4):

use case when

```
        select case when age>0 and age<13 then 'new born'
        when age>=13 and age<=19 then 'teen'
        .................
           ... end -- put here more condition as your need
```

Comment: this is simply a select script with cases Please read the question again, thank you

Comment: @SherazAhmed use case when in times of table creation

Answer (score 4):

You can use a calculated Field.

Your table design will be like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTbl](    
 [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
 [Age] DECIMAL(10,3) NOT NULL,  
 [AgeGroup]  AS (CASE WHEN Age < 1 THEN 'Newborn' 
                      WHEN Age BETWEEN 1 AND 13 THEN 'Kid' 
                      WHEN Age BETWEEN 13 AND 60 THEN 'Adult' 
                      WHEN Age > 60 THEN 'Elder' END)  
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ID]
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  (   [ID] ASC ))
```

Your field will be filled automatically, you just have to add your age.

Comment: as I mentioned in the question "I want to add a new column in existing SQL table"

Comment: This does not address the actual problem but Thank you for this. this increased my knowledge about  computed columns in SQL 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

First, you will have to create the `AgeGroup` column to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable
ADD AgeGroup VARCHAR(10)
```

As for making default values based on set conditions:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET AgeGroup = CASE WHEN yourTable.Age >= 0 AND yourTable.Age < 2 THEN 'NewBorn'
WHEN yourTable.Age >= 13 AND yourTable.Age <= 19 THEN 'Teen'
WHEN yourTable.Age >= 20 AND yourTable.Age <= 59 THEN 'Adult'
WHEN yourTable.Age >= 60 THEN 'Elder' END
```

Comment: Please read this in the question "One option is to create the column and then update but approach is out of the question here."

Comment: SQL Scripts like these are the closest you can get to generate default values. You can't simply add numbers into your `AgeGroup` column with the SQL Server user interface and expect to be able to configure SQL Server to know how to categorize the age group based on the age. If you could, it would be hard to find documentation on that. I would stick to an SQL script to generate default values on preset conditions.