# add not null column take values from other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, create-table

I have an existing table say, `Items` with `Id | CreateDate` (as DateTime) columns; want to add **`Year`** `int not null`, take the default year from the `CreateDate` column.

The `Year` value will be futer updated to different value, but just set it as default value when the column Year is added, because want to add non-nullable column to Year.

Is that possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a column with a default value to an existing table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92082/add-a-column-with-a-default-value-to-an-existing-table-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to add a new column and initialize it with the values from the other one, you can do:

```
-- add the column (as nullable)
alter table mytable add created_year int;

-- update the values on existing rows
update items set created_year = year(created_date);

-- make the column not nullable
alter table mytable alter column created_year int not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with another column -- unless you will feel the need to change the value of the column in the future.  Instead, just use a computed column:

```
alter table t add created_year as (year(created_date));
```

This is automatically calculated when you *query* the table, so it is always accurate, both for new rows and old rows.

Presumably, `created_date` is never updated.

Comment: that is not always the createdYear, the Year value will be futer updated to different value, but just as default value when the column Year is added