# How to initialize new column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core to interface with SQL Server. Suppose I add a new nullable property to an existing entity (i.e. a new nullable column to an existing table). How do I get the migration to set the newly added column to a default, non-null value in EXISTING rows in the table?

Suppose I add an `int?` property to my model. In the scaffolded migration code, I can add a `defaultValue` argument, like this:

```
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int?>(
            name: "MyNullableInt",
            table: "MyTable",
            nullable: true,
            defaultValue: 0); // Manually added this argument
```

but, as explained in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/92123/1637105),

> Keep in mind that if the column is nullable, then null will be the
>   value used for existing rows

And, in fact, a simple experiment shows that the newly added column has a value of NULL in existing rows in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke custom SQL during your migration:

```
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int?>(...)
migrationBuilder.Sql("UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable] SET [MyNullableInt] = 0");
```

*Please, note: this code and query are not tested! Modify it as appropriate.*