# Using a trigger to automatically assign a value to specific column on a new insert

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm struggling to find proper information on SQL Triggers.

My previous question got removed for it not being specific enough so hopefully this will do better.

I am trying to create a trigger that will assign RoleID 1 to every newly inserted row to my users table.

But I can't seem to figure it out.

```
AFTER INSERT on users
on EACH ROW
insert into users.RoleID values(1);
```

This doesn't seem to work.

And the examples and or information regarding triggers all focus on alerts or sending emails after an insert/drop or update.

Can it actually be done?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: The manual page is good https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you aren't creating you sql trigger with the correct keyword.

Try this

```sql
drop trigger if exists before_insert_users;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_users
    BEFORE INSERT ON users
    FOR EACH ROW
       BEGIN
            SET NEW.RoleID = 1;
        END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Note: RoleID will need to actually be a column on your table for this to work.

However, a trigger is not the best way to do this... See this SO post : [Add a column with a default value to an existing table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92082/add-a-column-with-a-default-value-to-an-existing-table-in-sql-server?rq=1)

Comment: This was very helpful! thank you!  but for an odd reason I eventually had to change the 1 in to a 0+1 because it would assign the role 0 to every newly created account. Reason still unknown.

Comment: @marten.philip what type are you using for roleID? (e.g. INT)